# asp.net publish и регистр букв

Tags: c#, nlog, visual-studio-2019

Пользуюсь `VS 2019`.

.Net Framework 4.6.1

NLog v. 4.6.8

Windows

Для логирования на сторне сервера решил использовать библиотеку [`NLog`](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/).

Все работает отлично. Если бы не одно НО. `VS` после публикации `NLog.dll` и `NLog.config` становится `Nlog.dll` и `Nlog.config` => т. е. регистр меняется. И самая соль в том, что для `Windows` все суперски (и я бы даже не заметил замены). Но целевая платформа - `linux` (`apache` + `mono`), в селдствии чего `Nlog` становится недееспособным. Если ручками заменить маленькую букву на большую, то все ок. Но все же - лень и программист - это одно целое ( в каком то смысле), т е хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс.

`Output publish`:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Loyalty.API, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  Loyalty.API -> C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\Loyalty.API\bin\Release\Loyalty.API.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: Loyalty.DAL, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>  Loyalty.DAL -> C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\Loyalty.DAL\bin\Release\Loyalty.DAL.dll
3>------ Build started: Project: Loyalty.BLL, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
3>  Loyalty.BLL -> C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\Loyalty.BLL\bin\Release\Loyalty.BLL.dll
4>------ Build started: Project: WebUI, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\ReportController.cs(157,49,157,74): warning CS0618: 'Helpers.GetStartDay(DateTime)' is obsolete: 'Устаревшая. Используйте метод расширения BeginDay(DateTime)'
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\ReportController.cs(157,26,157,75): warning CS0618: 'Helpers.ToUnixDateTime(DateTime)' is obsolete: 'Устаревшая. Используйте метод расширения ToUnixTime()'
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\ReportController.cs(158,47,158,70): warning CS0618: 'Helpers.GetEndDay(DateTime)' is obsolete: 'Устаревшая. Используйте метод расширения FinishDay(DateTime)'
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\ReportController.cs(158,24,158,71): warning CS0618: 'Helpers.ToUnixDateTime(DateTime)' is obsolete: 'Устаревшая. Используйте метод расширения ToUnixTime()'
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\ReportController.cs(241,33,241,67): warning CS0618: 'Helpers.GetStartDay(DateTime)' is obsolete: 'Устаревшая. Используйте метод расширения BeginDay(DateTime)'
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\ReportController.cs(242,31,242,61): warning CS0618: 'Helpers.GetEndDay(DateTime)' is obsolete: 'Устаревшая. Используйте метод расширения FinishDay(DateTime)'
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\ReportController.cs(280,29,280,63): warning CS0618: 'Helpers.GetStartDay(DateTime)' is obsolete: 'Устаревшая. Используйте метод расширения BeginDay(DateTime)'
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\ReportController.cs(281,27,281,57): warning CS0618: 'Helpers.GetEndDay(DateTime)' is obsolete: 'Устаревшая. Используйте метод расширения FinishDay(DateTime)'
4>C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Controllers\GiftСertificatesController.cs(27,26,27,34): warning CS0414: The field 'GiftСertificatesController.tempBars' is assigned but its value is never used
4>  WebUI -> C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\bin\WebUI.dll
5>------ Publish started: Project: WebUI, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
5>Connecting to C:\VladimirK\Loyalty...
5>Transformed Web.config using C:\VladimirK\MyProg\MyWork\20181203_ProjectMVC\2019_07_24_SrvDiscount\WebUI\Web.Release.config into obj\Release\TransformWebConfig\transformed\Web.config.
5>Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
5>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.
5>Deleting existing files...
5>Publishing folder /...
5>Publishing folder App_Code...
5>Publishing folder bin...
5>Publishing folder bin/roslyn...
5>Publishing folder Content...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/.github...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/dependencies...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/css...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/dependencies/js...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/dist...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/dist/css...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/scripts...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/src...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/src/js...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/src/less...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/src/sass...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/test...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/test/specs...
5>Publishing folder Content/bootstrap-slider/tpl...
5>Publishing folder Content/datatables...
5>Publishing folder Content/datetimepicker...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome/css...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome/fonts...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome/less...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome/scss...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome-old...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome-old/css...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome-old/js...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome-old/sprites...
5>Publishing folder Content/font-awesome-old/webfonts...
5>Publishing folder Content/images...
5>Publishing folder Content/multiSelect...
5>Publishing folder Content/site...
5>Publishing folder Content/site/Discount...
5>Publishing folder Content/site/Kassir...
5>Publishing folder Scripts...
5>Publishing folder Scripts/bootstrap...
5>Publishing folder Scripts/datetimepicker...
5>Publishing folder Scripts/jquery...
5>Publishing folder Scripts/site...
5>Publishing folder Scripts/site/Discount...
5>Publishing folder Views...
5>Publishing folder Views/Analitic...
5>Publishing folder Views/Article...
5>Publishing folder Views/ArticleGroupTree...
5>Publishing folder Views/Authorize...
5>Publishing folder Views/Bar...
5>Publishing folder Views/BarPrice...
5>Publishing folder Views/Discount...
5>Publishing folder Views/Discountcard...
5>Publishing folder Views/ForbiddenBar...
5>Publishing folder Views/GiftСertificates...
5>Publishing folder Views/Home...
5>Publishing folder Views/Info...
5>Publishing folder Views/Kassir...
5>Publishing folder Views/Perm...
5>Publishing folder Views/Receipt...
5>Publishing folder Views/Report...
5>Publishing folder Views/Scales...
5>Publishing folder Views/ScalesPrice...
5>Publishing folder Views/ScalesPrice/EditorTemplates...
5>Publishing folder Views/Shared...
5>Publishing folder Views/Shop...
5>Publishing folder Views/User...
5>Web App was published successfully file:///C:/VladimirK/Loyalty
5>
========== Build: 4 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Publish: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Вопрос: возможно ли заставить студию (или что там переименовывает) не делать этого?

Comment: Как вариант временного решения проблемы - в post-build script запилить переименовывание нужных файлов. Или они меняют регистр именно во время публикации?

Comment: @ГеннадийП во время публикации. При билжде все нормас.

Comment: А в логах что пишется?

Comment: Если руками вызвать `dotnet publish` поведение такое же? Версия Nlog какая?

Comment: @Vasek `dotnet publish` только в коре пашет

Comment: @ГеннадийП где именно вам логи нужны? я добавил в вопрорс `output` при паблише

Comment: Версия Nlog какая?

Comment: @Vasek NLog v. 4.6.8

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц В настройках можно увеличить детальность логов. Попробуйте там найти строчки где студия заливает NLog и с каким именем. Можете прямо по всему логу поискать `Nlog` с зависимым регистром, может чего найдет.

Answer (score 0):

В общем проблему решил.
Все дело было в галочке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Галочка была включена, и сбила меня с толку.

Т. е. я простго удалил ручкаи файл => после чего опубликовал снова проект, и все сделалось верно.

Comment: Весьма странная зависимость.